# Lockout feature on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing a plugin face recognition based ergonomics workstation for eclipse.  I have ergonomics checks such as posture and distance from the screen checks complete. My intention is to freeze or lockout a user from continuing using the IDE until they get ergonomically intact i.e. move further from the screen or sit up straight.

I was wondering if anyone knows of any feature to help me with this?

Would simply accessing the parent UI thread suffice or is there a better way ?

Comment: I don't believe eclipse IDE would have a feature to freeze itself. You can rather simulate it by blocking the UI thread though. Just run a while(true) loop and break out when something decides that the posture is right.

Comment: you can do it by `Display.syncExec( new Runnable() { public void run() { while( !postureGotRight ) { //I won't leave } } } );`